# How to manage Two WindowedApplication in Flex?

Tags: air, flex3

Case:

1) There are two .mxml files (Windowed Application): one is Log-in(Active Window/ Start up Window) and other is Main Window.

2) Main Window has viewstack

3) On log-in successful, log-inHandler called from Main Window.

4) log-inHandler access viewstack id of Main Window.

5) But viewstack id shows null.

Question:

1) How to solve this case?

Comment: You should show us some code, if you have an error

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not use 2 Windowed Applications
2. Make your Login page as a MXMLComponent
3. Add the Login page as a new NativeWindow from your main App, so you can communicate with it.